# Is it possible to specify (anchor or match) in a regular expression

Tags: regex

Can I specify I want the preceding character to be either (NOT A DIGIT) or (BEGINNING ANCHOR)?

I'm looking for "1/2", but I want to ignore cases like 21/22. I know I can rule out preceding or trailing digits like this:

```
/([^0-9])1\/2([^0-9])/
```

But that fails when the match happens at the beginning or end of the line. Are anchors ^ and & allowed in grouping clauses?

Comment: Have you tried using ^ or $ in a grouping clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to match something like `a1/2`, you can use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (provided that your regex implementation supports it):

```
irb(main):015:0> 'a1/2' =~ /(?<!\d)1\/2/
=> 1
irb(main):016:0> '11/2' =~ /(?<!\d)1\/2/
=> nil
```

Which is "the string `1/2`, not preceded by a digit".

If you can't use lookbehind, you can almost literally transfer your requirements into a regex like `/([^\d]|^)(1\/2)/`, which is "a character that is not a digit or the beginning of the phrase, followed by the string `1/2` (second capture group)".

Comment: I can't use lookbehind. But I see that you did answer with 
    /([^\d]|^)(1\/2)/
So yes, that's what I was looking for. I didn't know if anchors could be used in groups like that. I did try it (I'm using PHP), and it does work. Thanks!

Comment: @MM: The `preg_` family of regex functions should support lookbehind, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works for me is

```
([^0-9-]1\/2)|(^1\/2)
```

There are probably other more elegant options, perhaps using lookbehind.